# How to find total number of product in Google merchant account using Google API

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I can iterate products in my store by https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/products/list where I need to set maximum number of record I want.

Is there anyway to get total number of products in my account so that I can paging that data.

The nextPageToken is given for retrieve data but this token is not iterabale at least I can't iterate over this token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find any solution at net by surfing Google. Finally I come up with a solution by executing listproducts request of google merchant and count total product by looping entire product database. Its little bit wired, I know. Here is the code hint how I resolve the issue -

```
public $lastPageToken;
public function countTotalNumberOfProducts($pNextPageToken=NULL, $maxLoop=10){
    $totProducts=0;
    if(!empty($pNextPageToken)) $params['pageToken']=$pNextPageToken;
    $params['maxResults']=250;
    while (true) {
        $products = $this->objService->products->listProducts($this->merchantId, $params);
        foreach ($products->getResources() as $product) $totProducts++;
        $this->lastPageToken=$products->getNextPageToken();
        if (empty($this->lastPageToken)) break;
        $params['pageToken']=$products->nextPageToken;
        if(--$maxLoop<=0) break;
    }
    return $totProducts;
}
```

You can loop above function by reloading your page by javascript untill its not finish. This approach will avoid timeout if you have a lot of products.